# How to override method url_after_denied_access_when_signed_out in rails using clearance lib to change redirect url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I am using clearance library for my ruby on rails application auth, but I need to customize view  with my template login, I already override sessions method like this and it works but not for url_after_denied_access_when_signed_out method. also I want to know how redirect handle sign_in error input with flash to my custom login page

```
class SessionsController < Clearance::SessionsController
  protected
    def url_after_destroy
      login_path
    end

    def url_after_create
      dashboard_path
    end

    def url_after_denied_access_when_signed_out
      login_path
    end  
end
```

Comment: `url_after_denied_access_when_signed_in` move this method in application controller instead of `SessionsController`

Comment: why you used `protected` keyword multiple times?

Comment: @ashvin thank you so much ashvin, i'm new in rails, how about to send the flash failure message when sign in to my custom login page?

Comment: Can you please show me your sign in action from controller? Are you using flash messages of bootstrap?